# php generated html onclick variable not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

so I have this php code

```
$listing .= "<button onclick='updateValue(".$id.", ".$key.")'>change value</button>";
```

`$id` is an integer and works just fine, `key` is a reference from a for loop and the value translate well in the html code however the `key` value `table` is recognised as a variable instead of a string.

```
HTML: onclick="updateValue(3, table)"
```

I have tried evey trick I know (creating new variable with quotes, adding single quotes in the onclick and (string)$key ) to convert it as a string but nothing is working so far. any idea please ? is it even possible ?

Comment: scape the quotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add quotes to tell javascript that it's a string. Since you're inside an `echo` you'll need to escape the quotes:

```
$listing .= "<button onclick='updateValue(".$id.", \"".$key."\")'>change value</button>";
```

Comment: i think he's saying the `key` is a variabel

Comment: He can also do `' ". $key ." '` where the single quotes makes it a JS string and the double quotes escape it from PHP.

Comment: @LeviSchmidt No, the single quotes are already used to wrap the `onclick` action.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I read it as "if `$key` has the value `table`, javascript sees a variable `table` instead of the string `'table'`"

Comment: thats it, thanks a bunch, I learned something ! will accept asap

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
$listing .= "<button onclick='updateValue(".$id.", \"".$key."\")'>change value</button>";
```